# Retrieving database information via PHP within a dynamically created table row

Tags: php, dynamic, row, page-refresh

A rookie web developer here in need of assistance ...

I'm building an invoice application that allows the user to select a product from a drop down list, populate some fields based on that selection, then dynamically add another row to the invoice table so that they can start again with a different product.

The problem is that the product selections in the drop down list are populated via PHP from a MySQL database table. When the page loads, the initial invoice row is shown and the drop down list contains the product options ... however, I haven't quite figured out how to populate the subsequent (i.e. dynamic) product drop down lists.

Because the number of rows needed will vary, I want the user to be able to create only as many as will be needed.  I understand that the PHP will be read first, (i.e. prior to the user calling the Javascript function that creates the subsequent table rows), so my question is **how can I populate my dynamically created row/drop down lists with product names pulled from a database via PHP.** Will this require a page refresh?

Any direction you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to populate using PHP only, a page refresh will be required. You could instead use jQuery/AJAX or some other JavaScript library to pull in the data for your dynamic drop downs. Here's the jQuery doc's on using their GET ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a page refresh, you'll need to use Ajax to populate those subsequent dropdown lists (unless I've misinterpreted your question somehow - it is late here). Look into using Ajax with JQuery.

Comment: Thanks guys ... I've used AJAX elsewhere in the application (e.g. you can populate name, address, phone fields from the database table after selecting a customer from a drop down list without a page reload).  However, my current problem is that the new table rows are created by the user AFTER the page is loaded by calling a javascript function. Once the user creates a new row (containing a new drop down list), how does the list get the information from the database to populate the products? Hasn't the PHP already been processed at that point?  Thanks again!